# How can I access to different column in displayText function in QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I am going to change the display text for one of my `QTableView` column. I inherit from  `QStyledItemDelegate` class and change the definition of `displayText` according to the following:

```
QString CellIdDelegate::displayText(const QVariant &value, const QLocale &locale) const
{
    QString currentColumn = value.toString();
    QString anotherColumn = ....;

    return currentColumn + anotherColumn;
}
```

and then use `setItemDelegateForColumn`.

How I can access to the value of another column in my `QTableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't since displayText() is for exactly one cell. It's only meant to add e.g. a prefix or suffix. If you want to display other text, modify the data returned by Qt::DisplayRole accordingly. This is nothing for a delegate.

Comment: Thx, Could you explain more about your solution?

Comment: Don't know what more to explain. Take a look at QAbstractTableModel::data() and it's examples.